# <display:table> with SiteMesh and SessionAttribute

Tags: displaytag, sitemesh

I'm using SiteMesh to decorate my webapp.  I use a <%@ include file to include a dashboard JSP that has a display:table> which pulls data from a session scoped attribute.  If I do a c:out value ="${attributeName.List}"/> I can see the contents of the pojo that's loaded into the session attribute.  But when display:table name = "${attributeName.List}">.../display:table> will only render once.  After a refresh the table data disappears but the c:out data is still displayed.  So... SiteMesh has access to the session attribute, but display:table does not.

I've tried setting a page and a request scoped variable with c:set> but that doesn't help either.

I've also tried moving the table from the includes page to the decorator page and that didn't work either.

Any ideas on what could be the cause and where I might look to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Changed from using %include file to c:import and all is well.